# How can cabal use multiple cores while building local add-source'd dependency

Tags: haskell, cabal

My project is split through multiple subprojects, which are connected through `cabal sandbox add-source`. When I build "main" project via `cabal build -j`, cabal uses multiple cores, while if I do `cabal install --only-dependencies -j`, it would only use single core for each dependency.

This is very inconvenient, and it would be best for sources added with `cabal sandbox add-source` to also use multiple cores for each package.

Is this possible? Is it implemented, or is there a ticket for this already? I couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `-j` to `ghc`. For example: `cabal install --ghc-options='-j4'`